# Modifying an EXCEL formula in an automated process to save time

Tags: excel, average, formula

So I have a table for values of jewelry, basically a formula is in place that calculates a few parameters off an inventory file, and then spits out the average price.

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($S:$S,$B:$B,">=.10",$B:$B,"<=.19",$F:$F,"=VVS2",$E:$E,"=F",$A:$A,"=RD"), "-")
```

It looks like this:

[image]

Here's my issue though, I want to do that to hundreds of different table iterations. By iterations, I mean changing the jewelry/stone size. So .10-.19, .19-.29, all the way up to 11.0

Additionally, I'd like to do these to 6 or so different jewelry shapes, the example I provided is just for the keyword RD (ROUND).

Is there some automated way to modify the excel formula and sort of, plug it in? I know that's not very specific, but what I know for sure, is there's no way I can spend the time manually changing every cell for every different parameter, that would take just forever haha.

Appreciate any thoughts or suggestions, thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) because '*Is there some automated way to modify the excel formula and sort of, plug it in?*' is **not** a specific programming problem and adding narrative debris in the form of '*Appreciate any thoughts or suggestions, thank you.*' does nothing to change that. Haha.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short of writing a custom function with VBA, you could try the following approach:

Instead of hard-coding the parameters into the formula, put the parameters into cells and then refer to the cells in the formula. For example, put the values into the cells Z1 to Z6 like this:

[image]

Then you can change the formula to

```
=IFERROR(AVERAGEIFS($S:$S,$B:$B,">="&$Z$1,$B:$B,"<="&$Z$2,$F:$F,$Z$3,$E:$E,$Z$4,$A:$A,$Z$5), "-")
```

Now you can change any of the values in Z1 to Z6 to calculate with different parameters.

Comment: This is an extremely creative way of solving this issue Teylyn. Thank you very much!